# Laravel 5.2 - Staging to Live Server : 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.2 project working fine locally, after uploading to a live server I have a 'laravel' folder in my root directory and public folder under 'public_html/testsite'

My 'index.php' points to the correct '/bootstrap/autoload.php' and '/bootstrap/app.php'

Upon going to my 'url/testsite/' I get a blank page only (was working fine L5.0) firebug shows : 500 Internal Server Error with HTML : Reload the page to get source for...

index.php is loading by testing with `die()` before any 'require' methods, but after 'require... autoload.php' the `die()` is not working, however it is successfully calling autoload.php as a `die()` works within this file.

I'm not sure if this is a .htaccess issue, or maybe I had to set something up in cPanel last time for this folder (I can't remember). I'd appreciate any help!

Please note this Laravel project sits as a test site in a /testsite/ folder along with my current live site files.

Comment: God, after hours - I have no idea what I've done but it's worked - I wonder if it was creating a subdomain through cPanel which points to this folder? If someone could clarify that as the possible issue I had I'll write it as the solution.

Comment: Rewrite routing rules.

Comment: Yes, probably, as I've had to do the same. Creating the subdomain and pointing the root directly makes Laravel correctly cipher the url. On top of that the "RewriteBase / " rule, if you did that, may be what got rid of the 500 internal error.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst changing many things at once, I appeared to have solved this by setting up a subdomain within cPanel and setting this to my testsite/ folder.

This was on a server with my current website live under public_html/ and setting up a test laravel app(website) with under public_html/testsite/ to work as an independent site for testing.

The typical "change permissions on storage folder" suggested elsewhere on stackoverflow did not solve my issue so hopefully this helps someone in the same boat.